# .htaccess - RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters on Apache, but not Litespeed

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess to block some bad requests to my site, and trying to exclude one page. Everything works as expected on litespeed but when I am trying Apache I get this error: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

I've debugged it by excluding lots of code until I narrowed it down to this line of code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ajax_contactus\.php$
```

I am wondering, why does it fail on Apache and not Litespeed and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Unlikely if this is causing error. I suggest you show full .htaccess here.